# is there any prohibition popping fingers in the prayer mat?

Tags: salat

I heard that popping fingers in the prayer met whether it's after or before prayer, is not good.
Is that correct? Any reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all to have a ruling about prayer mats in Islam. Prayer mats should be introduced as something rather essential for praying or for the prayer in Islam. Which is not the case. In fact  whether you pray on the mat or on a ground is irrelevant as long as the ground you pray on is tahir.

Secondly as @MuziburUllah rather correctly said whatever you do during the prayer, which has no direct link to acts of the prayer could be regarded as sinful (depends on the acts and movements).

So as long as you don't do any of these things during the prayer, there's nothing wrong. However let's assume you do this in a mosque that could be regarded as disrespectful as even if you ended your prayer or are not praying you are in a place of worship a house of God (Allah).

See also: [Can we pray on something other than a prayer mat?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/60624/can-we-pray-on-something-other-than-a-prayer-mat)

Answer (score 0):

Its Mubah and Makrooh during Friday prayer as per my knowledge.

youtube.com/watch?v=xJJhS3EQGIc During prayer it is Makrooh e Tahreemi (not liked and sin as well) and while not in prayer its Mubah (not good not bad) but also Makrooh e Tahreemi during Friday Sermon because the conditions during sermon are same as in prayer.

اَللّٰهُ ورسوله أَعْلَم‎

Comment: please try to support your answer

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJJhS3EQGIc

During prayer it is Makrooh e Tahreemi (not liked and sin as well) and while not in prayer its Mubah (not good not bad) but also Makrooh e Tahreemi during Friday Sermon because the conditions during sermon are same as in prayer.

Comment: Edit your answer and add the information. Comments are not meant to last forever.

Answer (score -1):

Anything that is disrespectful during *namaz* is haram and, moreover, given that in *namaz* one's attention should be upon Allah, that is to be mindful of Him, popping fingers is inattentive and so haram.

**edit**

@Medi1Saif: But he does say that he's on the prayer mat and that signifies that ones attention ought to be on prayer.

Comment: OP clearly asks "whether it's after or before prayer". Which is not covered in this answer!

Comment: Being on the prayer mat only means one waits or one has performed a prayer and that's all. You are implying too much. And Allah told us a little of that is sinful.

Comment: @Medi1Saif: It implies the intention to perform *namaz*.

Comment: Intention for the prayer starts at the moment of takbir. We are human! There's no obligation I know of on having focus on prayer outside of it. It is certainly better, but this doesn't mean that one will lose this focus while doing whatever with your hands, the prayer mat or anything else.

Comment: @Medi1saif: And not when setting out to the  Mosque?